# Controlling database version

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio SQL Server project and it has been published to a bunch of databases. Users from time to time use it to publish new databases too.

The problem - sometimes users forget to check out latest version of a solution from `git` which may lead to some problems.

How I can prevent users from publishing a databases unless it is on a latest version? I log versions in a version db - it is just a guid with createdate. Also in a git folder, I have an `.xml` file with that guid (version number)

Comment: You'd need to implement something in the publication script that checks a remote locate to see if the version matches that on github, and then fail/warn the user if it doesn't. of course, you would need to ensure users can still offline deploy, but really, it's the users own fault for not completely a pull request first. Educate the users.

Comment: where i can put that check in visual studio, the thing which actually runs before db is published?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQL Server Data Tools Pre Deployment script to create logic to check a Version column on a table in a master server / database and compare it to the current version number in the dacpac or ispac that is attempting to be deployed and raise an error if the version attempted to be deployed is not the latest version. I don't like recommending a linked server but it could work well in this case and the credentials for the connection could be limited to the very specific master DB and table used for version comparison.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/how-to-specify-predeployment-or-postdeployment-scripts?view=sql-server-ver15